# How does Google Chrome's JS Crypto RNG Work?

Tags: cryptography, chrome, random

According to [caniuse](http://caniuse.com/#feat=getrandomvalues), Google Chrome has support for `crypto.getRandomValues()` for (presumably/hopefully) generating cryptographically secure random values. How is this implemented?

As there have been many issues with popular crypto libraries using their own homebrew RNGs, I'd like to know how much trust I can grant to this CSPRG.

Comment: Have you looked at the Chromium source code? https://chromium.googlesource.com/

Comment: It appears [that the specification heavily suggests using the system CSPRNG](https://www.w3.org/TR/WebCryptoAPI/#Crypto-description).

Answer (score 3):

On POSIX, Google Chrome [does in fact use `/dev/urandom`](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/base/+/master/rand_util_posix.cc#25):

```
class URandomFd {
    public:
        URandomFd() : fd_(open("/dev/urandom", O_RDONLY)) {
            DCHECK_GE(fd_, 0) << "Cannot open /dev/urandom: " << errno;
        }

    ~URandomFd() { close(fd_); }

    int fd() const { return fd_; }

    private:
        const int fd_;
};

// ...

void RandBytes(void* output, size_t output_length) {
    const int urandom_fd = g_urandom_fd.Pointer()->fd();
    const bool success =
        ReadFromFD(urandom_fd, static_cast<char*>(output), output_length);
    CHECK(success);
}
```